# Git Syntax: How to archive a repository?

Tags: git

So I have a git repository on my local computer that I want to archive (zip is fine) and upload to my server. Once the file has been uploaded to the server, I will extract the archive. I don't need any of the git information, so I think I need to use `git archive` but I'm not exactly sure how to use it...and the tutorials haven't been helping.

this is what I've got so far:

```
cd projectname
git archive master
```

Then I don't know what to do next. I want to create the archive in this directory:

```
./../_toDeploy/
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any one of the following will work:

```
git archive --output=../_toDeploy/ArchiveName.zip master
git archive -o ../_toDeploy/ArchiveName.zip master
```

To add a subdirectory inside the archive,

```
git archive --output=../_toDeploy/ArchiveName.zip --prefix=MyStuff/ master
```

See the [git-archive manual page](http://mirror.yandex.ru/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) for reference.

Comment: is it possible to put the repository inside a directory before archiving it?

Comment: Yes, use --prefix.  I've added this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following will zip up your master branch and put it in the folder you mentioned.

```
git archive --format=zip master > ../_toDeploy/repo.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Archive the last commit of your repo and getting rid of everything else (.git etc etc):

> git archive --format=tar.gz HEAD > file.tar.gz